# Can you create this element in an email with html/css?

Tags: html, css, email, layout, html-email

[image: email design]

The element I'm referring to is the **offset box that is positioned above, to the left and below the main box**.

Now creating this with regular HTML and CSS is super easy using absolute positioning and z-index.

However, in email HTML, where you're basically restricted to tables, I can't figure it out. Absolute positioning doesn't appear to be allowed. Most email clients strip it out. I'm not even sure if negative positioning is allowed.

How would you create this? Is it possible/worth even trying?

Comment: For email, you wouldn't use two 'cards' and overlay them like you would in web development. You can create this with tables and table cell really easily. See my pen here - https://codepen.io/Digital_Frankenstein/pen/GRJYOqd

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein is correct --- post it as the answer.

Comment: @mckeever02 I gather someone downvoted your question because it was too vague. Change "this element" to something like "an offset card/box"

Comment: Thanks so much @Digital_Frankenstein, amazing solution! This works really well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For email, you wouldn't use two 'cards' and overlay them like you would in web development. You can create this with tables and table cell really easily. See my pen here - codepen.io/Digital_Frankenstein/pen/GRJYOqd – Digital_Frankenstein

@digital_Frankenstein came up with a great solution.